# Postgres connection state stays active when an exception occurs

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, postgresql-11

The state of the connection stays `active` in pool, when there is an `exception` while executing a query or stored procedure through c#.

The `Npgsql` version that I am using is `4.1.7`.

Here is the code that I am trying to execute.

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = null;
NpgsqlDataAdapter sda = null;
NpgsqlConnection conn = null;
try {
    string sql = "a_test";
    conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;Username=admin;Password=test;Database=majordb;SearchPath=dbs;CommandTimeout=300;MaxPoolSize=500;Connection Idle Lifetime=180;Connection Pruning Interval=5;");
    cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sda = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    sda.Fill(dataTable);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
   //log
}
finally {
    if(null != sda)
    {
        try
        {
            sda.Dispose();                        
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
    try
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    try
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

If the above code executes properly without any exception, the connection state in pool goes to `idle`, which is correct. But if an exception occurs while executing, like below:

```
 "Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream ---> 
 System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt 
 failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
 connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."
```

The connection state in pool shows as `active` for about 5 mins or so, even though the `close/dispose` methods are called in `finally` block. This means the `close/dispose` did not properly executed by `Npgsql`. If the program keeps the connection state in pool active for every connection ran within 5 mins, then there can be an issue with `MaxPoolSize` error.

I wanted to see the `connection` state to `idle`, even when there is an exception. How do I do this.

Please note: I am not looking for a solution to the exception that I listed above. I am looking for a solution where the connection state is changed to `idle` from `active` when there is an exception while executing the above code.

To know if the connection state is `active` or not I used the following query:

```
SELECT
    pid,
    usename,
    application_name,
    datname,
    client_addr,
    rank() over (partition by client_addr order by backend_start ASC) as rank,
    state,
    state_change,
    current_timestamp,
    query,
    query_start,
    backend_start,
    FROM 
    pg_stat_activity
WHERE
    pid <> pg_backend_pid( )
AND
    application_name !~ '(?:psql)|(?:pgAdmin.+)'
AND
    datname = current_database() 
AND
    usename = current_user
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you open an issue with a full, runnable code sample on https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues?

Comment: I created an issue ticket. Here is the link https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/3447#issue-782227106